# Is there a way to deploy a .net MVC app to Azure such that current users continue using the old version of the app and new users use the new version?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app that is primarily client-side with a server API. The client-side app loads javascript modules lazily. When I recompile and redeploy, the names of the lazy-load files changes. If I deploy to PROD while a user is using the site, there will be problems as the module names will have changed.

Is there a way to have a secondary slot on Azure that new sessions will use, leaving the old app up while its sessions are still active? I would prefer to be able to deploy the site whenever I want without requiring a maintenance mode downtime, since the app will be used by thousands of people every day.

Comment: Hard to know exactly how are you "Lazy-Loading" your JS modules. But, can't you configure that loader to detect when the base version of the app is different from the lazy-loaded module' version? Once it detects they're different, you can force a reload of the entire window and have them matching once again

Comment: I'm using webpack for generating and loading the modules. My concern about just detecting a new version and reloading the page is that the user may have already done a bunch of work that they haven't saved yet. I'd hate to show them a message saying they have to reload and not save their work.